# With MongoDB, should I spilt a big collection into smaller ones?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
    category_id : 5
    data : (some data)
    (more data...)
}
```

And I have 15 categories, each category has 1 million records. Therefore, I have 15M documents in this collection.

I don't do very complicated queries. Mostly I get some documents from category n by:

```
db.collection.find({category_id: n, (some other conditions) })
```

I am wondering if it's better to split this main collection into 15 collections so that each of them only have documents belonging to certain category. Then I don't need to specify `category_id` in the query but use the corresponding collection for that category:

```
db.collection.find({ (some conditions) })
```

Will this make queries faster and any concerns?

Comment: The question is broad, but I will try to enumerate what comes to my mind. If you can identify some queries that are recurrent, it means you can identify clear use cases. For instance if you sometimes perform queries such as (cond1 cond2 cond3) and sometimes query such as (cond4 cond5 cond6) it means you could split you records in different collections. Of course one important question is if you always want to retrieve the full document or not. If not, it is a sign that it might be necessary to split your records. I guess, you also tried to add indexes.

Comment: If you don't feel it's your case (the fact that you can split in different collections), then you might be interested by sharding, which is basically splitting your records on an arbitrary key ! (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)

Comment: @LouisF. I think your first comment pretty much describes what I need to know. If you could elaborate a bit, that will be the answer. For example, adding indexes would be better than splitting it? I know it's a bit broad, but what you mentioned is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have any index, I would consider using indexes to yield nice performances. You have to be aware that indexing has a cost and you can't index all the fields. Splitting AND indexing might be a good fit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the following example. We have a User with following schema (does not intend to make any sense) :

```
{
"id":123
"posts" : [...],
"favorites" : [...],
"settings" : {},
"followers" : [...],
"email" : "anyEmail@email.com",
"age" : 29
}
```

On the one had, if you are sometimes querying fields by groups such as "favorites and followers" but you are not interested in the other fields, you could extract those fields in a separate collection and have a dedicated queries. The purpose here is to model depending on your use cases, not on your real world model !

What you need to wonder is "What are the actual use cases my collection is supporting ? ". If you support many, just split them apart.

On the other hand, even if you query on different fields but you always want to retrieve the whole document, then your collection might support your queries in a good way. One way to yield better performances would be to add indexes on the fields you are frequently using (official doc : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/). Ultimately, sharding might be what you are looking for, since the collection is huge and it might be relevant to split records based on an arbitrary attribute and distribute your DB over several machines.